# Dynamic Programming Problem: Maximum Accessible Area On A 2D Grid

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I recently encountered this dynamic programming problem and I wanted to see if anyone had thoughts on the approach to solve this. I had a hard time with this, and it's probably because I got stuck in the thinking of creating a huge tree to handle all of the possibilities.

### The Problem

> There is a character who can move around on an two-dimensional (x,y)
> coordinate grid. The character is placed at point (0,0).
>
> From (x, y) the character can move to (x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1),
> and (x, y-1).
>
> Some points are dangerous and contain land mines. To know which points
> are safe, we check whether the sum of the digits of abs(x) plus the sum of
> the digits of abs(y) are less than or equal to 23.
>
> For example, the point (64, -59) is not safe because 6 + 4 + 5 + 9 =
> 24, which is greater than 23. The point (105, -17) is safe because 1
>
> - 0 + 5 + 1 + 7 = 14, which is less than 23.
>
> How large is the area that the character can access?

Comment: Has the coordinate grid any kind of limit? Otherwise the safe are will obviously be infinite (1 trillion x 1 trillion = 2, and so on) Are the safe squares supposed to be adjacent? Another question, is in fact a 0x0 point? The character could surely move trough that line infinitely and always get nx0 = 0 (a safe square)

Comment: Are this points part of your triangles? `(319,219), (398,298)` ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToNGJ.png

Comment: How did you get to 698 without passing by 599 which is 23?

Comment: You didn't subtract the area covered by land mines in your square, or areas that are inaccessible because they are surrounded by mines.

Comment: @HikmatFarhat 599 is okay because the sum of the digits has to be less than _or equal to_ 23, so it's okay for the digits to add up to 23, but not 24.

Comment: @tym32167 I see your point. There are clearly spaces within my square that shouldn't be accessible based on the sum of the coordinate digits. I arrived at my solution by using a number that was very small (like 5) to figure out the area and then extrapolated it out to the larger number. Small numbers like 5 shouldn't have areas within them that aren't accessible because the "sum digits" isn't really taken into account at that scale. I oversimplified this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Having same assumption regarding `-1000, -1000 ... 1000, 1000` field max, here is simple BFS version written with `C#`

Function to check if point is safe

```
bool isSafe(int x, int y){
    return (sum(Math.Abs(x)) + sum(Math.Abs(y))) < 24;
}
```

Sum of digits (assuming non negative input)

```
int sum(int n){
    int ret = 0;        
    while(n > 0){
        ret += n%10;
        n = n/10;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

BFS algorithm

```
var visited = new bool[2000, 2000];
var queue = new Queue<(int x, int y)>();

var steps = new List<(int di, int dj)>() {(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)};

int count = 1; 

queue.Enqueue((0, 0));
visited[1000, 1000] = true;

while (queue.Count != 0)
{
    var point = queue.Dequeue();
    foreach (var step in steps)
        if (!visited[point.x + step.di + 1000, point.y + step.dj + 1000] && isSafe(point.x + step.di, point.y + step.dj))
        {
            count++;
            visited[point.x + step.di + 1000, point.y + step.dj + 1000] = true;
            queue.Enqueue((point.x + step.di, point.y + step.dj));
        }
}

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Output

```
592597
```

After discovering reachable cells you can see  figure

[image: ...]

Answer (score 1):

Let's just write a simple [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

At first, let's think how many cells can be visited, so our algorithm won't run forever. You can't go further than outside square with a top-left corner in *(999, 999)* and bottom-right corner in *(-999, -999)*, because one of coordinates on the square side will be *±999*, but *9 + 9 + 9 > 23*. There are *1999 * 1999 < 4M* points inside this square so DFS will be quite fast.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

const int SQUARE_SIDE = 1'000;

// v[i][j] is true if cell (i - SQUARE-SIDE, j - SQUARE_SIDE) was already
// visited during DFS, false otherwise.
bool v[2 * SQUARE_SIDE][2 * SQUARE_SIDE];
int answer = 0;

const struct {
  int dx;
  int dy;
} moves[] = {
    {1, 0},   // Up
    {-1, 0},  // Down
    {0, -1},  // Left
    {0, 1}    // Right
};

int calc_abs_sum(int n) {
  n = abs(n);
  int sum = 0;
  while (n) {
    sum += n % 10;
    n /= 10;
  }
  return sum;
}

void dfs(int x, int y) {
  // Add SQUARE_SIDE to make indices non-negative.
  v[x + SQUARE_SIDE][y + SQUARE_SIDE] = true;
  answer++;

  for (const auto &move : moves)
    if (calc_abs_sum(x + move.dx) + calc_abs_sum(y + move.dy) <= 23 &&
        !v[x + move.dx + SQUARE_SIDE][y + move.dy + SQUARE_SIDE]) {
      dfs(x + move.dx, y + move.dy);
    }
}

int main() {
  dfs(0, 0);
  std::cout << answer << std::endl;
}
```

which gives us *592597*.

Comment: Weird, I got `592597` using BFS

Comment: @tym32167 sorry, this code did diagonal moves on the grid, fixed, got 592597 too

Comment: @tym32167 sure why not

Comment: heh, I have same mistake with diagonal move. But anyway, that seems not affecting to result.

Comment: @tym32167 in the previous version I did only diagonal moves :) Btw it seems interesting that allowing diagonal moves along with horizontal doesn't change answer

Comment: Think it because whole area is only one connected component, at least it sounds logical :)

Comment: @tym32167 it's not since there is an infinite number of allowed cells, e.g. _(10^n, 0)_ but we got finite answer. Seems components are located in a distance one from another.

Comment: I wish I understood what was going here, but I’m clueless. Clearly I don’t have a good grasp of how DFS or BFS work. Unless the algorithm you’re using has more to it than a typical DFS algorithm. Do you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: @dwx dfs/bfs is typical graph algorhitms. There dozen information about that algorithms in internet. You only need to think about coordinate grid a bit differently, where each cell is a graph node, and only good cells (<=23) connected to each other.

Answer (score 1):

My answer was getting a bit too long for here so I documented a Java solution along with the thought process and a detailed explanation on the coordinate system in an article over at [HackerNoon](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-find-the-maximum-accessible-area-on-a-2d-grid-rhy3eiv).

Answer (score 1):

Here is JS version of Java code from https://hackernoon.com/how-to-find-the-maximum-accessible-area-on-a-2d-grid-rhy3eiv
Idea is the same. Returns 592597.

```js
const safePosition = 23;
const axisLength = 1000; 


const hasEMPMine = (x, y)=>{
  let tempX = Math.abs(x)
  let tempY = Math.abs(y)
  let sumX = 0;
    let sumY = 0;

  while(tempX > 0){
    sumX += tempX%10;
    tempX = Math.floor(tempX/10);
  }

  while(tempY>0){
    sumY +=tempY%10;
    tempY = Math.floor(tempY/10);
  }

  return sumX +sumY > safePosition;
}

function Create2DArray(rows, cols, defaultValue) {
    var arr = [];
  
    for(var i=0; i < rows; i++){
  
        arr.push([]);
  
        arr[i].push( new Array(cols));
  
        for(var j=0; j < cols; j++){
          arr[i][j] = defaultValue;
        }
    }
  
  return arr;
}

const CharacterGraphArea = () => {
  const booleanGraph = Create2DArray(2000, 2000, false);
  const characterLocationsArray = [];

  const possibleMovesArray = [{x: -1, y: 0}, {x:1, y:0}, {x:0, y:1}, {x:0, y: -1}]

  characterLocationsArray.push({x:0, y: 0});
  booleanGraph[0+axisLength][0+axisLength] = true;
  let area = 1;

  while(characterLocationsArray.length!==0){
    let lastLocation = characterLocationsArray.pop();
    possibleMovesArray.forEach(move=>      {
      let newX = lastLocation.x + move.x;
      let newY = lastLocation.y + move.y;
      let isSafe = !hasEMPMine(newX, newY);

      let x = newX + axisLength;
      let y = newY + axisLength;

      if(!booleanGraph[x][y] && isSafe){
        booleanGraph[x][y] = true;
        area = area + 1;
        characterLocationsArray.push({x:newX, y:newY});
      }});
  }

  return area;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late Answer, Here is the simplest **JS** version of the above problem solution:

```
     let danger_point = 24;

     function abs_sum(value){ // function to get abs sum
        value = Math.abs(value)
        let sum = 0;

        while (value) {
            sum += value % 10;
            value = Math.floor(value / 10);
        }
        return sum;
     }

     function is_safe(x, y){ // function to check if current point is safe
         return (abs_sum(x)+abs_sum(y) < danger_point)?true:false;
     }
    // We are simply visiting first quadrant only one by one point. this will check if the point is safe, it will simply add to the safe_points counter....
    function findPoints(){           
        let area = 1000;
        let total_points = 0, safe_points = 0;  
        for(let y=0; y<=area; y++){ // Y-AXIS Loop 
            for(let x=0; x<=area; x++){  // X-AXIS Loop                    
                if(is_safe(x,y)){
                    safe_points++;                         
                } 
                ++total_points;                   
            } 
        }
        // As there are 4 quadrants, we will multiply the result by 4
        console.log(`total points = ${total_points*4}`)
        console.log(`safe points = ${safe_points*4}`)
        
    }
    
    findPoints();
```